# Passing the variable to another Form

Tags: delphi

I got Form1 with some variables and I want to pass it to another Form3 where I'll use it. So I have two questions.

- How can I get access to the variable in another form? I suppose it will
  be similar to

  ```
  var newIdList:= Form1.idList
  ```
- When var idList get value in

  ```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);begin
    idList:=strtoint(edit1.text);
    end
  ```

  and I show new form in another can I still get value in `idList`?

  ```
  procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject); 
  begin
  form1.hide;
  form3.show;
  end
  ```

---

```
    unit Unit1;
    
    interface
    
    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;
    
    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        PageControl1: TPageControl;
        TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
        TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
        TabSheet3: TTabSheet;
        Label5: TLabel;
        Edit3: TEdit;
        Edit2: TEdit;
        Button3: TButton;
        Edit4: TEdit;
        Button2: TButton;
        Button1: TButton;
        Edit1: TEdit;
        Label1: TLabel;
        Label3: TLabel;
        Label2: TLabel;
        Edit5: TEdit;
        Label7: TLabel;
        Label6: TLabel;
        Button4: TButton;
        ListBox1: TListBox;
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Edit4Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Edit1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
        idList,imieList,nazwiskoList,adresList: TStringList;
      end;
    
    var
      Form1: TForm1;
      plik:TStringList;
      tempPlik:TextFile;
      st:string;
      linia_klient,linia_video:array[0..20] of string;
      id:integer;
    
    implementation
    
    uses Unit3;
    
    {$R *.dfm}
    
    .
    .
    .
    
    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var i:integer;
    begin
    Edit1.Text:='Witaj, Podaj ID klienta';
    Label1.Caption:='ID Klienta';
    idList:=TStringList.Create;
    imieList:=TStringList.Create;
    nazwiskoList:=TStringList.Create;
    adresList:=TStringList.Create;
    
    if (FileExists('idList.txt')=true) then idList.LoadFromFile('idList.txt') else idList.SaveToFile('idList.txt');
    if (FileExists('imieList.txt')=true) then imieList.LoadFromFile('imieList.txt') else imieList.SaveToFile('imieList.txt');
    if (FileExists('nazwiskoList.txt')=true) then nazwiskoList.LoadFromFile('nazwiskoList.txt') else nazwiskoList.SaveToFile('nazwiskoList.txt');
    if (FileExists('adresList.txt')=true) then adresList.LoadFromFile('adresList.txt') else adresList.SaveToFile('adresList.txt');
    
    AssignFile(tempPlik,'video.txt');
    Reset(tempPlik);
    i:=0;
    While Not Eof(tempPlik) do
      begin
        Readln(tempPlik,linia_video[i]);
        inc(i);
      end;
    
    CloseFile(tempPlik);
    end;
    
    
    
    procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      //Form1.Hide;
      Form3.Show;
    end;
    
    end.



unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);


  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

uses Unit1;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form3.Hide;
//Form1.Show;
end;



procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin

Label4.Caption:= intToStr(idList.Count);
end;

end.
```

Comment: You didn't follow my example! You need `Form1.idList.Count` instead of `idList.Count` on your 'last' line of code. (Because `idList` is a member of the `TForm1` class.)

Comment: @Dudi: Search for the article published by Marco Cantù in the Delphi Magazine issue 47 of July 1999 entitled "20 Rules For OOP In Delphi". You won't regret it.

Comment: @Dudi: Youn are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(I will assume that each form resides in its own unit.) First, you have to make sure that `idList` is accessible to other units. For example,

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    idList: integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

will not do, but

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    idList: integer;
  end;
```

is OK. In such case, all you need to do in `Unit2` is to add `Unit1` to its 'uses list' (press Alt+F11, or use File/'Use Unit...', while in `Unit2` or while editing `Form2`). Then you can use `Form1.idList` to access the variable anywhere inside `Unit2`. (`Form1` is the global instance variable of `TForm1` in `Unit1`).

For example,

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

uses Unit1;     // <-- Add manually, or press Alt+F11 (or use File/'Use Unit...')

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Form1.idList));
end;

end.
```

Comment: Ok I published variable, I had already add uses Unit1. But still that not working. I update my question about to code Unit1 and Unit3.

Not working means Undeclared `identifier: "idList"`

Answer (score 2):

'How can I get access to variable in another form?' - yes, as long as the variable is a public or published member and you have acess to the instance variable, you can access it in the same way as any other class instance variable.  Usually, this means adding the unit containing the 'Form1' class to the uses clause of the unit where access is desired.

'and I show new form in another can I still get value in idList?' - sure, as long as the form exists, you have access to the form instance variable and 'idList' is public or published.

Comment: public or publised means global?